# c# mysql decimal numbers with . or ,

Tags: c#, mysql, decimal

I have a table EXPENSES in a mysql database and one of the columns is AMMOUNT with decimal(10,2) as type. I have an application in C# (winforms) with a textbox that is used to insert values in the database.

```
string initialquery = "INSERT INTO EXPENSES (ID, E_DATE, AMMOUNT, PERSON, COMMENTS, T_ID) " +
                            "VALUES ('" + id + "', '" + date.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd") + "', '" + ammount + "', '" + person + "', '" + comments + "', '" + tid + "')";
        //yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss
        myMySqlConnection.Open();
        MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand(initialquery, myMySqlConnection);
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (lang == 2)
            MessageBox.Show("ΤΑ ΔΕΔΟΜΕΝΑ ΑΠΟΘΗΚΕΥΤΗΚΑΝ");
        else if (lang == 1)
            MessageBox.Show("DATA SAVED");
        myMySqlConnection.Close();
```

The problem has to do with the regional settings. If i set the format to GREEK. The decimal symbol is ",". When i try to insert a decimal value with a "," it doesn't accept it (is stored as 405 instead of 40,5). If i set the decimal symbol to"." and i have in the textbox 40.5 is stored correctly. If i set the Regional settings to ENGLISH and i set the decimal value to "," again is not working. Seems like that decimal numbers are accepted only when the decimal symbol is a "." I don't quite understand this. How can i make it accept the "," as a decimal operator?

Best Regards
George Georgiou

Comment: You should have to use parameters.

Comment: I think there must be a problem when i take the value from the textbox. Somethings wrong with decimal ammount = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text); This is the line that changes the number from 1.3 or 1,3 to 13 or just 1

Comment: why this difference between Regional settings?

Comment: you can do a test and replace , by .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve the issue, i used a not so correct code but here is what i did.
`string ammount = (textBox2.Text).Replace (",",".");`
and i insert the value as string. When the value is passed to the sql statement:

```
string initialquery = "INSERT INTO EXPENSES (ID, E_DATE, AMMOUNT, PERSON, COMMENTS, T_ID) " +
                                "VALUES ('" + id + "', '" + date.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd") + "', '" + ammount + "', '" + person + "', '" + comments + "', '" + tid + "')";
```

and its working

Comment: string ammount="";
            try
            {
                decimal number = Decimal.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                ammount = (textBox2.Text).Replace(",", ".");
                }   
                catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to convert");
                
            }

Answer (score 0):

I think you set the regional setting of your development machine but SQL Server still in en-us mode, so change the regional setting of your SQL server as well.

Hope it may accept the decimal as you want.

Comment: the think is that the database environment is from a webhosting site. I cannot change that. What i can do is change my system's Regional settings. What i cannot understand is that i have the REgional Settings to Greek and the operator is "," but when i try to insert something nothing is working. 3,2 is stored as 3 3.2 is stored as 32 :S Seems like the character "," doesn't exist on the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when converting from decimal to string.

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)

Quoting:

```
decimal value = -16325.62m;
// Display value using the invariant culture.
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Display value using the en-GB culture.
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")));
// Display value using the de-DE culture.
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")));
// This example displays the following output to the console:
//       -16325.62
//       -16325.62
//       -16325,62
```

Note that if your user use commas in his input, you can use the machine culture to convert from string to decimal and when building the query use the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to convert back to string with "." (period).

HTH